# Three.js Position and visibile issue

Tags: three.js

Currently, I am trying to dive deeper into grouped objects or better hierachic ordered objects. However I got a strange issue with the position and the visibility of a `object3D` and childs of those.

So i have a set of objects, a light source with is the main object so far, and a few spheres for example, which are childs of the the main object.

The problem is, that child objects, which are positioned behind another     object ( siblings ) ( from the camera view ) are visible. And all childs objects appear infront of the main object while those actually positioned behind the main object.

Sadly i can't reproduce this in a codePen so i had to take some pictures of the scene, many apologies for that.

In the pictures, the camera rotates clockwise around the light source (main object to the left).

1. [image]
2. [image]
3. [image]

So basically what I am doing is:

```
mObj = new THREE.Object3D();
mObj.add(new THREE.Mesh(someGeometry, someMaterial);
cObj = new THREE.Object3D();
cObj.add(new THREE.Mesh(someGeometry, someMaterial);
mObj.add(cObj);
scene.add(mObj);
```

Is that related to the object hierachic order or something else?

The second more negligible issue is, that on one of my pc's, those parts of objects which are dark (because of no lighting), generate those strange black/grey faces, which i cant explain. Maybe Graphicscard/driver or something?

Comment: I also can't reproduce such behaviour: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/prisoner849/fees9768/). The `sun` is the main object and the `planet`s are its children.

Comment: Ahh... i could! ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fees9768/5/)). I multiplied all sizes and distances, by one Lightyear (in Km). and get the same result as described. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the distance between these objects? It could be a floating point rounding issue. I've run into it myself.

If it's so, and you're getting flickering models, you'll need to keep your camera and the active model at the origin, and move the universe around you to keep precision in the important places (near the player).

Comment: Thanks for the hint. The distances and sizes are too big, so i have to find a new scale, which will be really tricky.

Comment: You may found a Solution to deal with very big floats (>10^9) or very small floats (<10^-7) in Three.js?

Comment: As I mentioned, usually it's not so important if you keep the user at the origin and move the universe around them, rather than vice versa.

Objects that are > 10^9 units away from the player will be outside WebGL's renderable frustrum anyway. 
When creating a new WebGLRenderer, you specify the near and far clipping planes. Having these set too large can also cause shuddering, and so it's best to work with these restrictions, rather than trying to brute force the hardware.